# Fetch one entity by url location header of Spring POST response in restangular

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, restangular

How can I fetch newly posted entity to Spring application which gives me back only "location" header of created resouce in response? I managed to get url from headers using

```
RestangularProvider.setFullResponse(true);
```

in restangular config (by the way, is there more elegant way to to this? Current solution forces me to use .data all over the place).

Response looks like this:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date    Sat, 03 Jan 2015 11:50:56 GMT
Expires 0
Location     https://localhost:8443/users/54a7d7a0ccf25ba3e97a51f9
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Application-Context   application
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
```

My restangular post controller action looks like this:

```
$scope.create = function () {
        $scope.users.post({
            name: $scope.name,
            surname: $scope.surname,
            title: $scope.title,
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password,
            phone: $scope.phone,
            skype: $scope.skype,
            roles: $scope.roles,
            nonLocked: $scope.nonLocked,
            nonExpired: $scope.nonExpired,
            credintialsNonExpired: $scope.credintialsNonExpired
        }).then(
                function (data) {
                    var location = data.headers('location');
                    var modal = $('#newUser');
                    modal.modal('hide');
                    modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
                    });
                    $('#roles').selectpicker('deselectAll');
                },
                function (error) {
                    if (error.status === 409) {
                        $('.alert').removeClass('hidden');
                    } else {
                        alert("Niestety wystąpił błąd, czy na pewno wypełniłeś wszystkie pola?");
                    }
                }
        );
```

The server-side Spring resource:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    public User findOneByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

How should I request for this particular resource using restangular and how push it into collection in order to refresh view?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've figured it out. All I need to use was

```
users.oneUrl('users', location).get().then(
                                    function (newUser) {
                                        $scope.users.push(newUser);
                                    });
```

after successful posting a new user and all works like a charm.